# botón que recorre arreglo en c#

Tags: c#, array

tengo una duda/peticion:

Como podria ser el codigo de un boton que recorra y muestre en un Label el valor de una posicion de un arreglo. Tengo el arreglo creado en un metodo y necesito que con un boton cada vez que lo presionas, te muestre el valor de la posicion del arreglo. Va a iniciar en la posicion 0 y tendra el valor 10(por ejemplo) y que al presionarlo, la siguiente posicion tiene el valor 12 y actualice en label.Text = "Numero" y asi sucesivamente hasta acabar con el arreglo. Como tendria que ser mi codigo?

Edit:

Tengo este codigo pero al presionar el boton me manda hasta la ultima posicion:

```
        {
            int[] myArr1 = new int[32]
                    {31 , 98 , 17 , 54 , 52 , 49 , 61 , 84 , 24 , 75
                , 11 , 33 , 70 , 50 , 46 , 87 , 43 , 55 , 39 , 96
                , 83 , 48 , 31 , 82 , 45 , 11 , 100 , 74 , 69 , 55
                , 98 , 61};

            int posicion = myArr1[0];

            foreach (int i in myArr1)
            {
                labelCylindroCount.Text = i.ToString();
                posicion++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que intentaste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema es que estas recorriendo todo el arreglo de un senton, como corrijo esto? asi de simple

```
//Declaramos una variable global el cual guardara la posicion actual
int Pos = 0
//(Opcional) a mi me gustaria declarar el arreglo global fuera del metodo
int[] myArr1 = new int[32]
                {31 , 98 , 17 , 54 , 52 , 49 , 61 , 84 , 24 , 75
            , 11 , 33 , 70 , 50 , 46 , 87 , 43 , 55 , 39 , 96
            , 83 , 48 , 31 , 82 , 45 , 11 , 100 , 74 , 69 , 55
            , 98 , 61};

Public void MostrarValor()
{
   //Verificamos si nuestro Pos es mayor que la lingitud del arreglo
   if(Pos >= MyArr1.Lenght)
   {
      //Reseteamos la variable Pos
      Pos = 0;
   }
   //Mostramos el valor en el Label
   label.Text = myArr1[Pos].ToString();
   //Aumentamos en 1 el valor de Pos
   Pos++;
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias amigo funciono a la perfeccion!